# How to add animated figure to sphinx?

Tags: django, python-sphinx

I am currently using sphinx for documenting my django project. And I would like to add documentation that includes animated figures. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By storing the image in your `docs` folder somewhere and declaring an [image using restructuredText](http://openalea.gforge.inria.fr/doc/openalea/doc/_build/html/source/sphinx/rest_syntax.html#image-directive):

```
.. image:: ../images/your_image.gif
```